# How to push elements in array and print the elements of array in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Here I tried to push my elements into array but I am not getting output in the p tag. May be there is any mistake in the code. Can someone help me out ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    
    var arr = [];
    var text = "";
    jQuery("#txtResult").click(function() 
    {
    //var text = "";
        //var string = jQuery("#txtPrint").html();
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().length == 5) 
            {
                arr.push("QQQ");
            }
            if (jQuery("#txtFirstNo").val().length == 5) 
            {
                arr.push("AA");
            }
            text += arr[i] + "<br>";
        }   
        
        jQuery("p").html(text);
    });
});
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
        <input type="text" id="txtFirstNo" name="txtFirstNo" placeholder="Enter value"  />
        <input type="submit" id="txtResult"/>
        <p id="txtPrint"></p>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `arr.length` is zero, so your loop will never loop.

Comment: why are you looping actually `for` ?

Comment: so what will be the exact code

Comment: Maybe explain better what you want to happen, providing the HTML, and the actions the user would perform, and the result it should have, because this code does nothing. Impossible to say what you intended to do.

Comment: Here the user will input 5 digits and the output should be QQQ and AA because both the condition gets true.
And my point is I want to push these elements into empty array and these both [QQQ and AA] should be stored in the array and same comes as the output

Comment: And i have included html code in the post

Comment: Why you have twice the same condition?

Comment: Because I want both the output on the screen and that's why I used for loop.

Comment: How about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/azbmLywx/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Simplified, looks like you just wanted smth like this

```
$("#txtResult").click(function(){
   let text = "";
   if ($("#txtFirstNo").val().length == 5) {
      text = "QQQ" + "<br>" + "AA" + "<br>";
   }
   $("p").html(text);
}
```

Comment: But what if i want to push elements in array and print that

Comment: Your original `push` and `print` worked fine - it was the `for` loop that wasn't working, but it was the entire logic over the need for a `for` loop that was lacking